# Add a column to a HDF5 FILE

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm currently trying to add a column to a HDF5 file that already exists.
Basically I have a column with the dates "%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm:%ss" and I would like to add a new column with the dates to the format "%Y-%m-%d".
My problem is that I have no idea how to do this, I tried with .append but without success. I want later compare these dates to others in order to keep only the ones I want.
If someone could help me it would be awesome (I'm coding in Python)!.

Thanks

Pierre

Comment: Do you really want to add a column? It is redundant and will have less information than the source column. As for how to add a column to an hdf5 dataset, as I understand it, that is not a trivial operation, which is why I am asking if you really want to add a column. If you really want to add a column to an existing dataset, then it would be much easier to answer your question if you provide both sample data and sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Phil!
I thought it was easier and a basic operation but apparently not.
Actually I have two files. First I have a "container", it contains this HDF5 dataset with 7 columns including the one with the dates. My other filer is a .csv file with a list of dates that I need. What I have to do is to create a new HDF5 dataset with only the data concerning the dates given in the csv file. (it's basically a filter)
I'm quiet new in this field and that's why I'm a bit lost. 
If you have any idea or link to help me it would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem by copying ma dataframe to a new file line by line and using at the same time my filter. Seems to work even if it takes some time. 
Thanks

Thanks again Phil, here is a code that I use to write a H5 file. Actually it takes approx 2 minutes to filter and write a new file. The .CSV file is a list of the dates that I want to keep (and so delete the rows concerning the other dates).

```
_hdf_store_path = config.get_hdf_store_path()
store = pd.HDFStore(os.path.join(_hdf_store_path, "household_{}_good.h5".format(household_id)), mode='w')
data_file = os.path.join(_hdf_store_path, "household_{}.h5".format(household_id))
data_store = pd.HDFStore(data_file)
df_1 = pd.concat([data_store[key] for key in data_store.keys()])
df_1_bis = df_1[df_1.date >= "2012-09-01"].sort("date")

dates = []
with open('Good_dates_{}_80pc.csv'.format(household_id), 'rb') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        str_line = line.decode("utf-8")
        dates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str_line.split()[0], "%Y-%m-%d"))

for day in dates:
    print("day =", day)
    day_after = day + datetime.timedelta(1)
    df_bis = df_1_bis[df_1_bis.date >= day]
    df = df_bis[df_bis.date <= day_after]
    store.append("day", df, min_itemsize={'ID': 15, 'sensor_id': 15, 'type': 15, 'date': 15, 'room': 15,
                                          'place': 15, 'value': 15})
store.close()
```

Comment: I am sure there is a cleaner and faster way using h5py and pandas. If you provide your sample code and data file(s), I will look at it.